# How do i strip special characters from the end of a string?

Tags: c#

I need to strip unknown characters from the end of a string returned from an SQL database. I also need to log when a special character occurs in the string.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: what are the special characters that need to be stripped? Why do you need to log when one is stripped? What have you tried and what are your initial thoughts?

Comment: That's the problem, i'm not sure what needs to be stripped. The program that populates the database is injecting unknown characters. Unfortunately i don't have control of this process. The ones who do control it want to know when this occurs. My initial thoughts would be to use a static method of the Char class. I do know the strings stored in the DB are only alphanumeric, it's appending these unknown chars to the end of the string. By performing an 'UrlEncodeUnicode' on the character i get this '%00++++++', im not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Just a hunch... is the DB column VARCHAR or CHAR?

Comment: Could you instead inverse the logic and look for a match of the known "good"data?  This would eliminate the need to understand the unknown characters.

Comment: That was what i was thinking. The thing is i would like to be able to log exactly what 'special' character occurred.

Comment: The DB columns is an nvarchar.

Comment: The %00++++++ would translate to a NULL character and a bunch of spaces. Smells like somewhere along the line there is a null-terminated string and then some code treats it as a fixed-length string, thus resulting in some junk at the end. The question is - where? Are you sure that this is what is stored in the DB, not what your code makes it?

Comment: Yes, im sure this is what is in the DB. The process is convoluted, it starts by an unmanaged c++ program that populates an access database with values, the values are then taken from the access database by a vbscript and pushed into an SQL database. Then my C# program pulls them out and sends them via a Web Service. You mentioned a null-terminated string, ,could this be coming from the c++ code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Trim() method to trim blanks or specific characters from the end of a string.  If you need to trim a certain number of characters you can use the Substring() method.  You can use Regexs (System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace) to match patterns in a string and detect when they occur.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966(VS.71).aspx) for more info.

If you need more help you'll need to provide a bit more info on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First define what are unknown characters (chars other than 0-9, a to z and A to Z ?) and put them in an array
Loop trough the characters of a string and check if the char occurs, if so remove.
you can also to a String.Replace with as param the unknown char, and replaceparam ''.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the problem is not precise yet this is a fast trick to do so:

```
string input;
...
var trimed = input.TrimEnd(new[] {'#','$',...} /* array of unwanted characters */);
if(trimed != input)
    myLogger.Log(input.Replace(trimed, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've specified that the legal characters are only alphanumeric, you could do something like this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(original, "^([0-9A-Za-z]*)(.*)$");
string good = m.Groups[1].Value;
string bad = m.Groups[2].Value;

if (bad.Length > 0)
{
    // log bad characters
}

Console.WriteLine(good);
```

Answer (score -1):

check out the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).Replace methods...there are lots of overloads.  You can use the Match methods for the logging to identify all matches.

```
        String badString = "HELLO WORLD!!!!";

        Regex regex = new Regex("!{1,}$" );

        String newString = regex.Replace(badString, String.Empty);
```